# connection to mysql database

Tags: java, mysql

I'm failing to connect to my database using the code below. when I run it it give the error "no connection" which is an error I put in case I fail to connect to my database, in this case bball... connect bball = new connect(); is the code I use to call this connect class but its refusing.

```
package trustproject;

//import connectionSql.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class connect {
    public Connection con;
    public PreparedStatement stat;
    public ResultSet res;


    public connect(){
    systemConnection();
    }

    public void systemConnection(){
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       con =(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bball", "root", "admin");
       stat = (PreparedStatement) con.createStatement();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successful Connection to database");

    } catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Connection");
    }

    }

    PreparedStatement prepareStatement(String insert_into_players_Name_Surname_IDNum_Position_Team) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("ERROR"); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

Comment: could you post an complete error log ? also check if your MSQL is running properly

Comment: instead of saying "No Connection", try doing `e.printStackTrace();` alongside it, This will help to identify the problem exactly

Comment: thank you but now its is giving  java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl cannot be cast to java.sql.PreparedStatement

Comment: Thank you, i managed to connect to my database. i simply removed the casting and simply put statements instead of preparestatement